# LINQ-SQL - Using static readonly fields within CompiledQuery.Compile?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I've encountered a strange issue using `CompiledQuery.Compile`. When trying to use a static readonly field within a query, I get the following error message:

```
Class member X is unmapped
```

If I move the field decleration out of the partial class into another class not related to LINQ-SQL, then I get the following:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

If I pass the fields through as an argument, then I see no errors and the query works fine and generates the expected SQL.

An example is as below:

```
partial class Order 
{
    public static readonly string Complete = "Complete";
    public static readonly string Pending = "Pending";

    public static readonly Func<DataContext, Order, bool> IsComplete =
        CompiledQuery.Compile((DataContext context, Order o) =>
           Complete == o.Status);
}
```

Usage:

```
var test = from o in db.Orders
           select new
           {
               IsComplete = Order.IsComplete(db, o)
           };
```

This generates the errors mentioned. If I add a `string[]` as another argument to the `CompiledQuery` then I see no errors. Also, If I modify the strings to be `const` instead of `static readonly` this works as well, but I imagine that is due to the values being assigned at compile time.

Is there any way of getting the `static readonly` fields working?

Comment: Have you tried using `public static readonly Func<DataContext, Order, bool> IsComplete = 
        CompiledQuery.Compile((DataContext context, Order o) => 
           Order.Complete == o.Status);`

Comment: Just tried this, it gives: `Class member Order.X is unmapped`.

Comment: Maybe try making all three fields into accessors instead?  `public static string Complete { get { return "Complete"; } }`  Does it give the same result?

Comment: Does  it have to be a field, can it be a constant `public const string Complete="Complete"`

Comment: Same result, when in the `Order` partial class and another class.

Comment: @BobVale I could use a `const` but this a seperate assembly and I was trying to avoid the issue whereby all referencing assemblies don't need updating if I only update a single one. Not a problem as such, but I wondered if there was an answer for this first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is occuring because Linq-To-Sql is trying to translate your expression into the backend SQL, because the logic sees an unmapped class member it cannot cope with converting it.

I would suggest you create a wrapping property to do the work for you

```
partial class Order  { 

  public static readonly string Complete = "Complete"; 
  public static readonly string Pending = "Pending"; 

  private static readonly Func<DataContext, Order, bool> _isComplete;

  public static Func<DataContext, Order, bool> IsComplete {
    get {
      if (_isComplete == null) {
        var complete=Complete; 
        _isComplete CompiledQuery.Compile((DataContext context, Order o) => 
                                                       complete == o.Status); 
      }
      return _isComplete;
    }
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Not entirely sure why this works, but it does. Also, the readonly properties are not allowed on the `Func`. Cheers.

Comment: I've removed the readonly from the property call (caused by too much copy and pasting).  The reason this works is becuase you end up passing a local variable into the Compiled lambda instead of the actual property.  This allows LinqToSql to evaluate it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem if you're not mixing normal queries and compiled queries. The following works and will give you better performance overall, at the cost of not being able to reuse a simple `IsCompleted` compiled everywhere you like.

```
public static readonly Func<YourDataContext, IEnumerable<Order>> GetCompletedOrders =
    CompiledQuery.Compile((YourDataContext context) =>
        context.Orders.Where(o => Complete == o.Status));
```